# nativescript - Command gradlew.bat failed with exit code 1

Tags: android, angular, nativescript, gradlew

I am making a nativescript app and when I run tns run android I get this error:

Unable to apply changes on device: FA53YYJ05603. Error is: spawn gradlew.bat ENOENT.

If I do tns build andoid I get this error:

Command gradlew.bat failed with exit code 1

I have tried tns platform remove android and then tns platform add android and still get the error.

I have the gradlew.bat file in platform/android

I am really new to nativescript.